# How do you insert weekends into data only containing weekday dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, database

I have 2 year daily closing prices for Bitcoin, from 1st August 2016 to 31st July 2018. Bitcoin can be traded 7 days a week so this data includes the dates of weekends:

[image]

I want to add more data sets, including closing prices for platinum, and the NASDAQ index, and these data sets only contain dates for 5 days a week, skipping weekends since no trading occurs then.

I have a column of the full week dates over my two year period, but I want to include in a second column, the corresponding closing prices of platinum and NASDAQ, but the data gets muddled since it skips weekends. E.g. the 29th July was last Sunday, but if I copied over the data from NASDAQ, that day would correspond to Friday since it doesn't have Saturday or Sunday in its dates.

In Excel, how can I insert these weekend dates, whilst keeping the closing prices in line with the correct corresponding dates for NASDAQ and platinum? I want the closing prices on the inserted weekends to be 0.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` may be of use to you

Comment: Thank you @cybernetic.nomad ! Could you please explain, in relation to this particular situation how I might use this function?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A25,AA$2:AB$1000,2)
```

Where `A25` contains the date (per your screen cap) and `AA$2:AB:1000` is the range containing the NASDAQ index, 2 is the number of the column in the range specified (`AA$2:AB$1000` in the example)

Comment: I'm having some issues still. My friend nor I don't know why we can't get it to work but this is the command I'm using:

=LOOKUP(B5,BTC!$A$29:$A$758,BTC!$F$29:$F$758)

Where B5 is the first date for NASDAQ entries, BTC! is the sheet with Bitcoin entries, $A$29:$A$758 is the column with the dates for bitcoin, on the bitcoin sheet, and $F$29:$F$:758 is the closing prices for bitcoin, but all that happens is I get repeated entries when I drag down the formula. Any ideas why this is happening? thanks

Comment: Change it to: ` =LOOKUP(B5,BTC!$A$29:$F$758,6)`

Comment: Still nothing! That just comes up with #N/A

Comment: Missed the typo, it's **V**LOOKUP, not LOOKUP

Comment: VLOOKUP had the same problem, but actually we found out it's a silly reason it didn't work! Excel demands that you have all your data in oldest to newest order, so I had to sort all my data, then use: =LOOKUP(B5,BTC!$A$29:$A$758,BTC!$F$29:$F$758)

Once I'd done that, it was all working! Thank you for taking your time to help me, much appreciated!